# PHP Codeigniter - Upload a certificate template(image)

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

How can I use the image uploaded as a certificate template and the code will pull the data from database and fill the certificate information like the venue , names, date, etc. and when the user view his/her certificate it will show as pdf.
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can use FPDF class to generate PDF files with php and put your values in places required, here is the link, you will have to design that template using this class.

http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/#p-222
After importing the files you can load them as a library:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/fpdi.php";
class PdfPHP extends fpdi {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and then:
`$this->load->library('PdfPHP');`
More info on how to load a library into ci: https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/ (it's a different PHP function, but the same idea)